# UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LogisticRegression was fitted with feature names

Tags: python, flask, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I wrote a program in Flask to get input from users to enter the lengths and widths to predict the fish type but as soon as I enter it shows an error known as

```
UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LogisticRegression was fitted 
with feature names
```

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

df=pd.read_csv('Fish.csv')
df.head()

X = df.drop('Species', axis=1)
y = df['Species']

cols = X.columns
index = X.index

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
random=RandomForestClassifier()
random.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=random.predict(X_test)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
score=accuracy_score(y_test,y_pred)

# Create a Pickle file  
import pickle
pickle_out = open("model.pkl","wb")
pickle.dump(logistic_model, pickle_out)
pickle_out.close()

logistic_model.predict([[242.0,23.2,25.4,30.0,11.5200,4.0200]])
```

```
import numpy as np
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template

app=Flask(__name__)
pickle_in = open("model.pkl","rb")
random = pickle.load(pickle_in)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/predict',methods=["POST"])
def predict():
    """
    For rendering results on HTML GUI
    """
    int_features = [x for x in request.form.values()]
    final_features = [np.array(int_features)]
    prediction = random.predict(final_features)
    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text = 'The fish belongs to species {}'.format(str(prediction)))

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Data Set
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/aungpyaeap/fish-market

Answer (score 7):

I also faced same warning:
UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LogisticRegression was fitted with feature names.

This warning actually saying while fitting data to our model during `model.fit()`, that `dataframe X_train` has got attribute names but while you are trying to predict using dataframe or numpy array converted into row vector, you're not providing features/attribute names to that tuples to which you want to do prediction.

For understanding clearly what i meant to say, just see sample image below:[image: Click here to see example image]

Hope this might help beginners while doing prediction on unseen data by model

Comment: Thank you ! This helped me solve the same error message.

x_make_this_prediction = pd.DataFrame(make_this_prediction, columns=['latitude','longitude',
                                                                    'accommodates','room_type',
                                                                    'review_scores_rating']) # Creating the DataFrame

Answer (score 4):

Your `X` and `y` is a pandas dataframe. Before fitting it to Random forest classifier make it a numpy array like,

```
X = X.values
y = y.values
```

After this do the train test split,

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=0)
```

Now Fit the model (the code is same as yours below),

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
random = RandomForestClassifier()
random.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred=random.predict(X_test)
```

In the flask app, you are giving input in numpy array but during the training you have pandas dataframe that's why that warning was raised. Now, it should work properly!