# UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but DecisionTreeClassifier was fitted with feature names

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I am learning machine learning from Programming with Mosh channel.
I got desired output in this case.

```
output=array(['HipHop', 'Acoustic', 'Classical'], dtype=object)
```

but there is a warning like this and I cannot find which part is wrong.

```
C:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:450: UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but DecisionTreeClassifier was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(
```

Do you know how can I correct this?

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
music_data=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\machine learning tutorial\\Python Tutorial Supplementary Materials\\music.csv')
y=music_data['genre']
X=music_data.drop(columns=['genre'])

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X,y)
predictions=model.predict([[22,1],[26,0],[39,1]])
predictions
```

Comment: Your issue have been already solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69326639/sklearn-warning-valid-feature-names-in-version-1-0) .

Answer (score 0):

After line 5, before "model = DecisionTreeClassifier" add two more lines:

```
X = X.values
y = y.values
```

A more in-depth solution and explanation can be found here:
[UserWarning: X does not have valid feature names, but LogisticRegression was fitted with feature names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73095119/userwarning-x-does-not-have-valid-feature-names-but-logisticregression-was-fit)

Answer (score 0):

I was also following Mosh tutorial and got the same problem as you did.
it got resolved by amending the line 8 from:

`model.fit(X, y)`

to

```
model.fit(X.values, y)
```

and that fixed the problem.
Apparently it has something to do with headers in the data source, but I am not 100% sure. Just know it it did fix the problem.